# BizTalk 2016 BRE

Tags: c#, azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-2016

I am trying to replace some characters in a JSON file in BRE, I want to use this in BRE pipeline.

Below is the JSON input

```
{
    "Attributes": "{}",
    "Credentials": "[]",
    "AccessRules": "[]",
    "EmployeeNumber": "A",

}
```

I want to replace "{}" to {} and "[]" to [] using BRE Below is the final JSON what it needs to look like.

```
{
    "Attributes": {},
    "Credentials": [],
    "AccessRules": [],
    "EmployeeNumber": "A",

}
```

Note : For some Reason I am not able to create Empty JSON Object and Array through BizTalk JSON Encoder Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should have two actions in your BRE rule

```
Replace the string "{}" in the message body with {}

Replace the string "[]" in the message body with []
```